# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'route'

Tags: python, flask

`Here is my app.py`
** As you can see that I've been trying to redirect my add_user() function to ../src/Form/basicForm.js but I'm unable to. I think I've been missing something. **

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy 
from models import User, Admin

POSTGRES = {
    'user': 'postgres',
    'pw': 'jarvis123@#$',
    'db': 'flask_database',
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': '5432',
}

app = Flask(__name__)
db=SQLAlchemy(app)
app.config['DEBUG']=True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://%(user)s:\%(pw)s@%(host)s:%(port)s/%(db)s' % POSTGRES

db.init_app(app)
@app.route('/adduser/<int:id>', methods=['GET','POST '])
def add_user():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.args.get('name')
        email = request.args.get('email')
        password_hash = request.args.get('password_hash')
        try:
            user = User(
                name=name,
                email=email,
                password_hash=password_hash
            )
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
            # return render_template("../src/Form/basicForm.js")
        except exception as e:
            return (str(e))
    return render("../src/Form/basicForm.js")
```

`Here is the error:`
**It has been showing Attribute error related to 'route' **

````
File "/home/manoj/Desktop/registration-app/api/app.py", line 36, in <module>
    @app.route('/adduser/<int:id>', methods=['GET','POST '])
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'route'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! registration-app@0.1.0 start-flask-api: `cd api && venv/bin/flask run`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the registration-app@0.1.0 start-flask-api script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/manoj/.npm/_logs/2021-04-02T08_55_02_861Z-debug.log```
````

Answer (score 0):

This Can Be Happening if You have a route with function name `app()`

Like This:

```
@app.route('/')
def app():
    return "Hello World"
```

Change the Function Name to:

```
@app.route('/')
def _app():
    return "Hello World"
```

Comment: Can you Please Post The Whole Code with All Routes

Comment: Please go through the link. https://ibb.co/hVKZXYx and https://ibb.co/Z1D2JPH

Comment: Try Changing Your File Name from app to something other

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following lines at the end of your app.py file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5050, debug=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

the run file app.py